# Moving picture on canvas using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have this JS part:

```
var layer1 = document.getElementById('layer1');
ctx1 = layer1.getContext('2d');

if (cellId == 'layer1x') {
    x1 = cellValue;
}

if (cellId == 'layer1y') {
    y1 = cellValue;
}

if (cellId == 'layer1z') {}

var item1 = new Image();
item1.src = "images/sheep.png";
item1.addEventListener("load", function () {
    ctx1.drawImage(item1, x1, y1)
}, false);
```

How to delete an existing image and how to display the only new with new coordinates.

Comment: Perhaps consider using canvas library like [Fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't 'delete' the painted image, you can clear the canvas.

`ctx.clearRect(X,Y,W,H);`

You can read more about canvas here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas/Tutorial

Comment: Call this before you draw the new image `ctx1.clearRect(0,0, layer1.width, layer1.height);`